# python -m http.server is not working for POST

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to run my webpage in localhost. I am using python http.server to run the code in localhost. It works for GET requests but not working for POST.

```
python -m http.server --cgi 8080
```

It is showing

"Error code: 501

Message: Can only POST to CGI scripts.

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation."

Comment: What would you expect it to do with a POST?

Comment: I am expecting to POST a json file

Comment: What do you *mean*, exactly? What you're running is a static server for files in a local directory, it's not going to magically start some kind of interactive web application.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Note that OP uses `--cgi` in the command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGI scripts have to be in a special directory, like cgi-bin:

> Only directory-based CGI are used
>
> cgi_directories¶
>
> This defaults to ['/cgi-bin', '/htbin'] and describes directories to treat as containing CGI scripts.

So you can use them this way:

In a terminal, run: `python3 -m http.server --cgi 8080`

and in another one:

```
$ cat cgi-bin/foo.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print('200 OK\r\n\r\nfoo')
$ chmod u+x cgi-bin/foo.py
$ curl http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/foo.py -X POST
foo
```